# Optimizing this SQL query by reducing the inner queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following postgres query that gives me the results I want but I feel like it isn't optimized as it's running the same inner query twice. I've tried a group by but it keeps saying i have to add xdata.column_name to the group by. I have to get the `total_count` because I'm creating pagination with these results. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT total.total_count, xdata.* FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, CAST(celery_taskresult.meta -> 'args' ->> 0 AS INT) AS user_id, celery_taskresult.meta ->> 'name' AS task_name FROM celery_taskresult) AS x 
    WHERE x.user_id IS NOT NULL) as xdata
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(z.id) AS total_count, 0 AS b FROM (SELECT *, CAST(celery_taskresult.meta -> 'args' ->> 0 AS INT) AS user_id, celery_taskresult.meta ->> 'name' AS task_name FROM celery_taskresult) AS z 
    WHERE z.user_id IS NOT NULL) as total ON 0 = total.b
ORDER BY xdata.id ASC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used postgresql in a while but selecting `COUNT(*) OVER()` should work

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_count, 
         xdata.* 
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT *, 
                         CAST(celery_taskresult.meta -> 'args' ->> 0 AS INT) AS user_id, 
                         celery_taskresult.meta ->> 'name' AS task_name 
                    FROM celery_taskresult) AS X 
           WHERE x.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS xdata
ORDER BY xdata.id ASC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

EDIT: Docs on PostgreSQL window functions - [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_with_clause.htm.
For example

With cte as (select * from a) select * from cte;

Replace select * from a with your inner select and use it.

Comment: While this may make the query easier to read, the question is about query optimization. This could have negative effects on how long the query takes to run. The values selected in the CTE are cached and, when selected from, the indexes of the base tables can't be used. Since indexes can be used on data pulled in a subquery, the original subqueries may actually be faster.

Comment: But repeated subqueries does not have any where clause.There is no reason to use index in these same subqueries.if these had where clause I would have agreed with you.

Comment: There is where clause on the user_id, the join could also use an index if one is present. This is, of course, all theoretical since we don't know much detail about the schema.

Comment: Ok I focused running of repeated subqueries one time.As you say this is therotical.But user id where could also be used in cte subquery and so it would use index and would be cached.It is required to examine execution plans with cte and without cte.Thank you for your comments